# MacBook Pro, OS X 10.7.5 with Windows 7 x64 2 partition

Tags: windows-7, macos, mac, partitioning, exfat

I want to backup both Mac & Windows partitions onto a completely OS interchangeable Seagate Backup Plus 2 Tb drive. (I don't know what program was used to do that.) I've read that formatting to ExFAT is the way to accomplish that, but I'm not clear on exactly what would be reformatted. Is is just the Seagate or is it the Mac/Win data. I don't want to lose my data to a reformat. (I don't have a Mac system DVD.)

I'm not particularly literate in these things, so please keep it simple. Many thanks!

Comment: I haven't found a way to do that and instead use [WinClone](http://twocanoes.com/products/mac/winclone) to backup the Bootcamp partition locally, which I then back-up to my attached external drive.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "Is it just the Seagate drive or is it the Mac/Win data?"

I am assuming you mean "is it the entire contents of the drive or just the Mac/Win data?"

In which case it would depend on how you have the drive setup and the settings you choose on whatever software you're using, but if you *reformat* the whole drive then you will lose all of the data. It is also possible to format just part of the drive if you have separate partitions on the drive.

Comment: I have not used the Seagate at all; it's my two partitions on my computer that hold my data. I want to both read & write from both partitions to/from the Seagate. Is it just the Seagate that needs to be reformatted? If so, how do I accomplish that?